# Resize background image according to window height and width

Tags: css

How to rezise background image according to window height and width? An example is here: http://themeforest.net/item/inesta-responsive-one-page-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/6648341

Rezise the window and scroll down. The background image is same height as the window height.

Comment: Have you tried [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for `background-size: cover;`. To position the background you can use `background-position: center center;`.

The cover will set it to fill the whole width and height without stretching the image. By centering it you will see the center of the axis that is overflowing.